# Object name JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Есть простая функция которая проверяет, является ли свойство прототипа или своё. Как получить имя объекта?

```js
var m = {
  turn_on: false,
};
var toster = {
  has_timer: true
};
toster.__proto__ = m;

function checker(object_name, property_name) {
  if (object_name.hasOwnProperty(property_name)) {
    return "The " + String(object_name.name) + " has own =>" + property_name;
  }
  return "False";
}
console.log(checker(toster, "has_timer"));
```

Node cli => The [object Object] has own => has_timer

Chrome cli => The undefined has own => has_timer

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object_name.name)` так будет понятнее

Comment: @Darth не будет, потому что у объектов нет свойства name

Comment: Добавь пример как ты вызываешь, и какой результат ожидаешь при этом

Comment: @Grundy Однако там лежит не undefined, а некий `[Object object]`. Думаю, ТС было бы интересно на него взглянуть

Comment: в примере у меня выводит: `The undefined has own =>has_timer`

Comment: можешь в этом убедиться запустив сниппет

Comment: поправил, запускал из редактора